# how to properly specify nested OData $expand to Angular $odataresource directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, odata

In my Angular app I'm using $odataresource directive to consume OData v4 feed in the following way:

```
http://10.0.0.4:8080/InformationProduct?$expand=DataEntities($expand=DataSources)
```

This query runs fine in Fiddler, Postman, as well as any modern browser:

```
{
    @odata.context: "http://10.0.0.4:8080/$metadata#InformationProduct",
    value: [{
        ID: 1,
        Name: "ODM Dashboard",
        Description: "ODM Dashboard",
        Governance_ID: 1,
        PerformanceMetric_ID: 1,
        DataEntities: [{
            ID: 1,
            Name: "Data Entity 1",
            Description: "Data Entity 1",
            InformationProduct_ID: 1,
            BiMeasure_ID: null,
            BiFact_ID: null,
            BiDimension_ID: 1,
            DataSources: [{
                ID: 40,
                Category: "Service Performance",
                SourceSystemName: "Account Improvement Plan",
                SourceSystemOwner: null,
                SourceSystemLocation: null,
                SourceSystemTeam: null,
                SourceSystemNetworkSegment: null,
                SourceSystemOsType: null,
                SourceDatabaseName: null,
                SourceDatabaseType: null,
                SourceDatabaseVersion: null,
                BiFact_ID: null
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to implement the same query within my Angular controller like this:

```
function getData(){
    $odataresource("http://windows-10:8080/InformationProduct")
        .odata()
        .expand('SourceTools')
        .expand('DataEntities','DataSources')
    {}
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://windows-10:8080/InformationProduct?$expand=SourceTools,DataEntities/DataSources 400 (Bad Request)
```

It is clear, that $odataresource does not translate `.expand('DataEntities','DataSources')`

into `$expand=DataEntities($expand=DataSources)`  as expected

What is the proper way to have $odataresource directive produce such nested $expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources) state that you need to use the isodatav4 property to let it know that you are using a v4 endpoint:

> To enable this behavior set the isodatav4 property to true when
>   invoking the $odataresource method:

```
User = $odataresource('/user', {}, {}, {
    odatakey: 'id',
    isodatav4: true
});
```

Then use the expand method like this:

```
var result = User.odata().expand("roles", "role").query();
//  /user?$expand=roles($expand=role)
```

For you, this means that you have the right expand call already, you just need to add the `isodatav4` flag to  `$odataresource("http://windows-10:8080/InformationProduct")` to make `$odataresource("http://windows-10:8080/InformationProduct", {}, {}, { isodatav4: true })`